# Заменить теги ссылками.

Tags: preg_match, php, preg_replace

**Дано:**
Набор текстов из WYSIWYG-редактора. Хранятся в базе данных. Всякие разные там теги, среди которых встречаются такого типа:

```
<username class='username' uid='12345'>MyNick</username>
```

**Задача:**
При выводе заменить все эти теги на ссылку в личный кабинет пользователя, вместо ника, указанного внутри <username></username>, вставить ник из базы данных, соответствующий uid (а вдруг уже поменялся, запись-то давно сделана была), проверить, загрузил ли пользователь себе мини-аватарку, и если да, то вставить её перед ником.
**Моё решение:**
1) для каждого текста ищем все теги, вытаскиваем из них uid

```
$user_pattern = "/<username class=.* uid=\"(.*)\">.*<\/username>/";
preg_match_all($user_pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $value){
    if(!in_array($value[1],$uids)){$uids[]=$value[1];}
}
```

2) Делаем запрос к бд, составляем массив из готовых ссылок (сразу для всех текстов):

```
$query=$dbh->query(" SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE users.id IN (".implode(',',$uids).")"); 
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
while($row=$query->fetch()){
    $uid=$row['id'];
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/user_icons/$uid.png")){
        $icon="<img src='/images/user_icons/$uid.png' class='icon_in_text'>";
    }else{
        $icon="";
    }
    $users[$uid]="$icon <a href='/user/$uid/' class='username'>".$row['username']."</a>"; 
}
```

3) Заменяем <username> на то, что нужно нам (это всё в цикле для каждого текста):

```
preg_match_all($user_pattern, text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $value){
    $text=str_replace($value[0],$users[$value[1]],text);
}
```

**Всё, всё работает. Вопрос к вам, хешкодеры:**  Не слишком ли я намудрил в третьем шаге? У меня получается 2 раза выполняется функция preg_match_all (в 1 и 3 пункте). А сразу заменить не получится, иначе несколько раз будет выполняться запрос к бд, с разными наборами id для каждого текста. Может быть запомнить результаты из пункта 1 в массиве, и в 3 пункте обращаться к массиву, а не искать заново?
И используется str_replace, в которой я не уверен, не даст ли она сбой при работе с кириллицей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не слишком ли я намудрил в третьем шаге?

Если это будет выполняться по крону / единоразово, то на переписывании кода вы потеряете больше ресурсов, чем выиграете.

Но, вообще, после выполнения первой регулярки у вас в $matches уже должны лежать полные вхождения строки ($matches[0..i][0]), которые можно использовать для поиска и замены. У массива в качестве ключей могут быть не только uid, но и полные строки, если пугает длина - можно брать какой-нибудь короткий хэш от них. По-хорошему можно оформить каждое совпадение классом/массивом, чтобы им можно было легко управлять, задавая все атрибуты, которые могут потом понадобиться в работе.

> И используется str_replace, в которой я не уверен, не даст ли она сбой при работе с кириллицей.

Я с этим вплотную не сталкивался, но стэковерфлоу подсказал, что эта функция работает напрямую с байтами, а не с символами, поэтому должно заменять как есть, главное, чтобы везде использовалась одна и та же кодировка.